# javafx @font-face css error "loadStyleSheetUnprivileged"

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to load a custom font in JavaFx css using this method

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf');
}
```

I've done every thing proper with the correct path but I'm getting this error

```
Nov 28, 2015 4:49:18 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not load @font-face font [file:/C:/Users/RootUser/Desktop/Java8%20projects/RemoteViewer/out/production/JavaFxApplication/application/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf]
```

This is my project structure "screenshot"

[image]

**Note** I'm using intellij Idea as my IDE.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the CSS file located in your project? And where is the `ttf` located?

Comment: @Tunaki It is located in the `src` package just as the fonts folder, I don't think the problem is with the path coz i have cross checked

Comment: Try with `/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf`. You should edit your post with the location of each file involved though, it is very important is problem like these.

Comment: @Tunaki If I do that,the IDE is  returning `Cannot resolve file Roboto-Medium.ttf`

Comment: @ColnsAbt Can you add the project structure in the question?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I have uploaded a screen shot of my project structure, I guess that will add some detail.

Comment: @ColnsAbt According to the screenshot, the path is correct. Can you check if the css file is also present in the `out` directory? My wild guess would be that IntelliJ is ignoring resources and not copying them to the output directory.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Yeah,It's present `out>production>JavaFxApplication>application>application.css`, By the way, this is also the first time I'm encountering this error and it seems unusual

Comment: @ColnsAbt Are the fonts available?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Yeah,every thing is available,and I'm also surprised by the outcome.

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? Also, try without the `font-family`.

Comment: @Tunaki I'm using JDK8, and also the whole application runs perfectly but can't load the custom fonts.

Comment: I understand you're using Java 8 but JavaFX is tricky so you need to specify the precise version (output of `java -version`).

Comment: @Tunaki I only have one JDK on the system, I uninstalled all the rest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This a bug in JavaFX (8). If there's a space in the font file's pathname, it won't load, and throw an exception, as it happened in with you.

This means that we shouldn't load fonts from a CSS file, unless we're sure the file path won't contain any spaces.

There is a better, safe way to load fonts (~first line inside `main()`):

```
Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/font.ttf"), 16);
```

Comment: Thanks, also found this out the hard way

Comment: @CollinsA Oh sorry, this question is a year old. Though it will help for others.

Answer (score 0):

For others who have come to this answer when searching:

The same error also occurs if you accidently leave out the quotes for the font name in a style, e.g.:

```
-fx-font-family: Monserrat;
```

is wrong, it needs to be

```
-fx-font-family: 'Montserrat';
```